# Web Page - 3d earthquake visualization - Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, 3d, camera

I have never written any silverlight apps but I am looking to write a 3d viewer for earthquakes and have it run from my web site.

I would like to create a simple viewer so the user can change the "camera" ie their perspective. The view could contain up to 10,000 objects in the 3d space.

I want the ability to quickly view this - I have seen this on a Power Basic application and want to do this for the web.

I have a current web site at http://canterburyquakelive.co.nz for earthquakes in Canterbury New Zeaalnd and I want to learn the basics so that it can be more interactive.

I want to say for example (to start) place 2 objects in a "space" that I can define and move the camera in real time.

The system must support up to 10,000 objects in the end of the day.

Each object can be a simple circle - no need for special pixel shaders

I am unsure of the exact functionallity of the system at the moment so if I can find a tutorial that allows me to place someone (a circle) into a 3d world (space) and change the camera that would be good.

Any ideas appreciated - there seems to be so much about 3d and silverlight that I may be getting lost in the "gloss" of new features where I need some basics and I can learn and adapt over time.

** Added comment + image **
Basically I am waiting to create a page that look like this using Silverlight. But I am open to any technology.

[image: This is what I want to create]

Comment: Are you tied to a particular solution? For instance if somebody had a non-silverlight solution, or even a non-programming solution would you be interested?

Comment: Because I am trying to provide this on a web site I would like a solution that will work in a browser. I make no money out of the project on earthquakes and would like to make it simpler for the average person to visualize what we have been going though ove the last 18 months.  I am looking into Silverlight 5 and its 3d support - well I will give it a try if I can. But if you have othe solutions I would love to hear.

Comment: You've not specified exactly what you want to show in your visualisation. If it is simply about showing the point location of earthquake events then maybe you could look at the [google earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/).

Comment: @OlduwanSteve: your comment could well be an answer.

Comment: @chac Maybe I'm just being pedantic, but for me it's an answer to a slightly different question. I guess in an ideal world Chris would modify his question to take into account my comments then I could post my answer to his actual question :)

Comment: @OlduwanSteve: cause Chris said *Any ideas appreciated*, and I switched to Ubuntu some time ago (now I don't want to install Silverlight), I took your comment as very constructive.

Comment: @chac interesting, you do not want to install Silverlight but you are more than willing to install the Google Earth Plug-in

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c# - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @Stilgar: yes, maybe I'm prevenute, but I used Flash to develop Web deployable 3D, and now I'm switching to WebGL...

Comment: @chac correct me if I am wrong but the Google Earth Plug-In is not WebGL based but is an actual plugin installed in the browser and is not even available on Linux.

Comment: @Stilgar: you are absolutely right, and your comment valuable (I think) for the decision Chris will take...

Answer (score 1):

I've never done 3D in silverlight so I can't exactly answer your question as asked but in general to display geographic markers in a 'real' 3D terrain is quite involved. At a minimum you're probably looking at:

- Obtaining binary height data files (last time I looked, NASA gives this away)
- Reading and interpreting said files to get 'bitmap' height data
- Choosing and dealing with projections (e.g. UTM)
- Deciding how to tesselate your bitmap height data

If you want it textured you'll need to also obtain satellite data for that, again converting or processing it to account for projection.

You could ignore the terrain height, but that may not simplify things depending on how 'bumpy' your terrain is.

For a pre-defined small enough area, you could perhaps pre-author a 3d model of the terrain in some 3D package but displaying your markers will still require a projection from long/lat into your 3D space, and you'll still need to know terrain height (unless you do mesh collision with the static model).

Rendering the markers is pretty straightforward by comparison, choose from:

- Use a 3D model e.g. a 'pin head' (simple but not always visible)
- Render a regular n-gon with 'viewer facing' polygons (resolution independent but maybe ugly)
- Render a quad with a circle texture on it (low poly but what size texture to choose?)

There are probably libraries that do some or all of this for you, so if you are set on rolling your own then some of the things I've mentioned could form the basis for your search.

However, given what you've described of your site and situation I suspect you'd be better off avoiding all that work by using a pre-existing solution. E.g. the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/).

Comment: I have updated my question to include a graphic of what I am trying to represent. SO basically to start with I would like to just put the image of the ground and rotate it around. I would like to specify that the top left of the image is at a LAT/LNG pair (could be easily just a number X/Y) and also the bottom right. Then I want to rotate around this item and zoom in and out.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider 3D web plugins that -granted- take you away from Silverlight but that might speed up your development process.  I'm thinking in particular of e.g. the Blender 3D web plugin. I can understand the need to write your own viewer, but think twice before you re-invent the wheel. Good luck!