# Looking for sample code Silverlight 3d c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, 3d, perspectivecamera

I am wanting to create a visualization of earthquakes like this image below where I can move the camera and show 100's or 1000's of small circular objects.
[image: This is what I want to create]
 .
All the demos I can find online show a single object rotating around - i want to rotate the camera over a known world.

My world would be like the map rectangle in the image above and my data (circles) to be shown above/below that.

So my world should be say if using Lat/Lng something like

172, -40 to 179, -45 and have a Z (depth)
or it could be just as easily
23000, 14000 to 29000, 19000

My image would be displayed on those coordinates at a Z of 0

Can anyone show me a demo or sample code to do that?

Cheers

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# - Web Page - 3d earthquake visualization - Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734877/c-sharp-web-page-3d-earthquake-visualization-silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

If it is at all possible, consider Silverlight 5 which provides a somewhat limited version of the XNA framework.

This has the ability to do some very advanced 3D graphics and should fit your needs assuming you have the time to learn how to do it.

I can immediately point you at a CodeProject series:
[3D Basics using Silverlight 5 and XNA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289499/3D-basics-using-Silverlight-5-and-XNA) and
[3D Basics using Silverlight 5 and XNA Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293968/3D-Basics-using-Silverlight-5-and-XNA-Part-2)

But Searching Google for "Silverlight 5 XNA" returns quite a few hits.

Regards,
Steven

Comment: Agreed, this will utilize the gpu, and is much better than anything you could do in past versions of Silverlight.